# search maven dependencies in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

`Ctrl-H` in an eclipse workspace allows you to do a full text search of all the code created by developers in a given eclipse workspace.  But the source code of the maven dependencies is not included in the searches.

How can a person do a full text search of all the source code contained in the jars that are located within the maven dependencies of an eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

I have also research this but I could not find any suitable way to look inside the jar and jre or maven dependencies. From my research, I have found that there is an eclipse plugin, which does enable this search everywhere in your project. The information to the plugin, you can find [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) . After downloading this plugin, you can search through `search -> InstaSearch` and bottom, a new view will be openned. You write there what you want to find and it brings you all occurrences, wherever the text is.